# Using URI::URL to extract username and password from SFTP URL

Tags: perl, url, version

I was using `URI::URL` from http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/URI/URL.pm in my program to extract the scheme, host, username, password, and path from URLs and life was good. Then I installed Net::SFTP and it apparently installed `URI::URL` from http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI.pm .
The error I get with sftp URLs is:

> Can't locate object method "user" via package "URI::_foreign" at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/URI/WithBase.pm line 50.

Ftp URLs work fine though. How do I tell the module to treat sftp URLs the same way it treats ftp URLS?

Comment: The module that you want to use looks like it has not been maintained since 1997. Perhaps your question should be how to do what you need with tools that were updated this millennium. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [this page](http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/), lcwa is an  unauthorized release, meaning it named modules with the same name as existing modules. Use at your own risk.

There used to be a module named URI::URL, but it was obsoleted. It shouldn't be used. It current exists as a thin wrapper around URI for backwards compatibility. You should be using [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) instead.

Installing [URI::sftp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3asftp) should make URI learn of the `sftp` URI scheme.